# Adding labels and textviews in a stack view programmatically in swift

Tags: swift, uilabel, uitextview, uistackview

How can I do to have a title, followed by a few lines of text, followed by a title again and again few lines of text constrained in the middle of a view controller programmatically?

My goal is to have bolded for the titles, and it would be nice to have the textview lines incremented also.

My idea was to create 2 labels, and 2 textviews. And adding those to a textview in this order: label1, t1, label2, t2.

But it doesn't seem to work. I try to avoid defining the same textviews and labels many times. textviews add up if I copy its definition twice but not for labels (maybe it is view related?)

I tried with UIbuttons and it worked.

This is what I tried so far:

```
import UIKit

class HowToSetupProIGVC: UIViewController {
    deinit {print("deinit")}

    let textView: UITextView = {
        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.backgroundColor = .blue //bkgdColor
        textView.textAlignment = .left
        //textView.frame = CGRect(x: 5, y: 5, width: 5, height: 5)
        textView.tintColor = .black
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false //enable autolayout
        textView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        textView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
        return textView
    }()
    
    let label: UILabel = {
        let l = UILabel(frame:CGRect.zero)
        //l.frame = CGRect(x: 5, y: 5, width: 5, height: 5)
        l.backgroundColor = .green //bkgdColor
        l.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .headline)
        l.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false //enable autolayout
        l.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 22).isActive = true
        l.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
        return l
    }()
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.modalUI(arrowButton: false)
        self.view.backgroundColor = bkgdColor
        customStackHTSProIG ()

    }
    
    
}

extension HowToSetupProIGVC {
    
    func customStackHTSProIG () {
        
        let label1 = label
        let label2 = label
        
        let t1 = textView
        let t2 = textView
        
        label1.text = "Title1:"
        label2.text = "title2:"
        
        t1.text = """
            1. On your profile tap menu
            2. Tap settings
            3. Tap accounts
            4. Tap set up professional account
            """
            
        t2.text = """
            1. On your profile tap "Edit profile"
            2. Link your created page to your account
            """
        
        //StackView
        let stackHTS = UIStackView()
        stackHTS.axis = NSLayoutConstraint.Axis.vertical
        stackHTS.distribution = .fillEqually
        stackHTS.alignment = .center
        stackHTS.spacing = 5
        stackHTS.backgroundColor = .red
       
        
        //Add StackView + elements
        stackHTS.addArrangedSubview(label1)
        stackHTS.addArrangedSubview(t1)
        stackHTS.addArrangedSubview(label2)
        stackHTS.addArrangedSubview(t2)
        
        self.view.addSubview(stackHTS)
        
        
        //Constraints StackView
        stackHTS.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  = false
        stackHTS.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        stackHTS.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        //stackHTS.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 88).isActive = true
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UILabel` & `UITextView` are both UIKit classes written in Objective-C. They are reference types, NOT value types.

When you write following -

```
let label1 = label
let label2 = label
        
let t1 = textView
let t2 = textView
```

Both `label1` & `label2` are pointing to the one & same instance of `UILabel`. So is the case for `t1` & `t2` as well.

When you add them like this -

```
//Add StackView + elements
stackHTS.addArrangedSubview(label1)
stackHTS.addArrangedSubview(t1)
stackHTS.addArrangedSubview(label2)
stackHTS.addArrangedSubview(t2)
```

You expect 2 labels and 2 textViews to be added to the StackView. You are adding only 1 label and 1 textView though.

You expect to see all of following -

```
        label1.text = "Title1:"
        label2.text = "title2:"
        
        t1.text = """
            1. On your profile tap menu
            2. Tap settings
            3. Tap accounts
            4. Tap set up professional account
            """
            
        t2.text = """
            1. On your profile tap "Edit profile"
            2. Link your created page to your account
            """
```

However you are only seeing following -

```
        label2.text = "title2:"
        
        t2.text = """
            1. On your profile tap "Edit profile"
            2. Link your created page to your account
            """
```

Solutions -

1. Create two separate instances of `UITextView` & `UILabel` like you have already done for the first two and Add these new instances to stack view as well.
2. Use one `UILabel` and remove everything else. Use `NSAttributedString` API to stylize your text as you want for different sections / paragraphs and assign it to `UILabel.attributedText`.